# Configure email notification with Calendar app

Tags: calendar, google-calendar

If I create an appointment in the Android* calendar application, I can add a reminder that will pop-up on my phone at the configured time.  It will automatically synchronise the event with Google Calendar (which is great!).

If I create the appointment with Google Calendar, I can add a reminder that will either be sent as an email, be sent as a text message or appear as a web-browser pop-up.  Again, the event will be synchronised with the phone.  I really like the Google Calendar email notifications as they appear in Gmail Manager as well as on the phone, so I'm much more likely to notice the reminders when I'm at work and have my phone on silent.

Is there any way to create an appointment in the Android calendar application and at the same time set up a reminder to come by email rather than as a calendar reminder notification?

Thanks in advance for the help.

* HTC Desire, CyanogenMod 7.1.0, Android 2.3.7

Answer (score 1):

- Go *Calendar*
- Tap the event you want to add a reminder for (or create a new event)
- Tap *Add reminder*
- To the right of the time drop down you should see *Notification* as a drop down tap this.
- Select *email*

Tried on Android 4.1, Google Nexus 5.

Hope this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score -2):

It is possible to create **default event reminds** by accessing your calender through the [Google Calendar website](https://calendar.google.com).

1. Access your settings

   - Wrench Icon > Setting
2. Access your calendar's specific settings

   - Calendars tab > Click on your calendar
3. Add a default reminder

   - Notifications tab > Add a reminder

Most mobile devices with calendar applications support pop-up reminders and may chime and show a an alert to notify you of the event.  I prefer this method so that I can specify a special sound for calendar notifications vs normal emails, but this is where you would create an email notification.

**It seems you want to remove the pop-up notifications, and add an email notification.**

You can create a new calendar and adjust it's notifications if you don't want to receive an email for every event/only want email notifications for specific events.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. But OP wants to use calendar app.

Comment: This is using the calendar app.

Comment: But you've said in the beginning of the post that it can be done by using calendar website. Correct me if I'm wrong or misunderstood you.

Comment: It's a one time process that may require login to the website.  I am unsure as to whether these detailed options are available within the calendar app itself, but are definitely available and only need to be set up a single time within the web interface.

Comment: @earthmeLon, You're suggestion doesn't work anyway.

Comment: @HappyNomad Works great for me.  Any part in particular you're getting stuck on?  What Android device are you using?

Comment: I'm using Samsung Galaxy S2.  I'm wondering if it's because the calendar is not in the device's primary account, but I have no way to test this.